# how to find upper and lower diagonal matrix matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I tried to use matlab to find the upper and lower diagonal matrix in matlab

here is the idea

if I have matrix 4x4

```
 1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16
```

the main diagonal is

```
1 6 11 16
```

but the second upper diagonal is

```
2 7 12
```

and the lower is

```
5 10 15
```

so there is `triu` and `tril` but to to write it or use any other function in matlab to find this upper and lower diagonal in matrix.

Answer (score 2):

just use `diag` , for example

```
 diag(A,0)   % main diagonal, also diag(A)
 diag(A,-1)  % lower diagonal
 diag(A,1)   % upper ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple linear indexing to get any diagonal of a matrix. All you need to know is the linear index of the first element and the number of rows in the matrix:

```
 >> [m n] = size(A);
```

Get the main diagonal on the matrix (first element index is 1):

```
 >> A( 1 : ( m+1 ) : end )
```

Get the lower diagonal (first index is 2):

```
 >> A( 2 : ( m+1 ) : end )
```

Get the upper diagonal (first index is `m+1`):

```
>> A( (m+1) : (m+1) : end )
```