# I have a NXN matrix and i am trying to get one vector with the diagonal entries and anther with all the entries that are not in the diagona

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I not trying to just get one column of entry above or below the diagonal. I am try to separate the matrix into two vectors one with the diagonal and the other with all the entries that are not the diagonal.

Comment: IMHO this is not a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023862/how-to-find-upper-and-lower-diagonal-matrix-matlab). The answers to that question will not work for this one. (I agree that it's not a very good question, but it's not a dupe).

Comment: @RobertP. a simple adaptation: `selDiag = false(n);selDiag(1:(n+1):n)=true; dElem = M(selDiag);nonDiagElem=M(~selDiag);`. bottom line: not a good question = close, if it is **significantly** improved - vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a matrix `M` of size `n`-by-`n` you can simply

```
selDiag = false(n);
selDiag(1:(n+1):end)=true; %// create a alogical indexing of all diagonal entries
dElem = M(selDiag); %// select all the elements on the diagonal
nonDiagElem=M(~selDiag); %// select all the rest of the elements
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach might be a bit simpler than Shai's:

```
A = magic(n)               %// sample matrix
b = diag(A)                %// or A(logical(eye(n)));
c = A(~logical(eye(n))).'  %// off-diagonal elements

A =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

b =
    16
    11
     6
     1

c =
     5     9     4     2     7    14     3    10    15    13     8    12
```